# Enforce static title in UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, ios9, uitabbar

I am using a `UITabBar` whose first tab relates to a `UINavigationController`. The `UINavigationController`'s root view controller's `viewWillAppear:` sets that view controller's (and hence the navigation controller's) title to the current month symbol. This implicitly also changes the title shown in the tab bar.

How can I achieve an alternative situation where the tab bar shows a static title (e.g. `"Calendar"`) whereas its related navigation controller still shows the dynamic one (e.g. `"December"`)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution now works for me. `MonthViewController` is the `UINavigationController`s root view controller.

```
class MonthViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // calculate monthSymbol ...

        self.title = monthSymbol

        let tabBarController = self.navigationController!.parentViewController as! UITabBarController
        tabBarController.tabBar.items![0].title = "Calendar"
    }
}
```